# Combine two observables with one being optional

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two observables which I need to combine.

```
observA: | ----- A B C D E ---------------------------F G H------>
observB: | ------------------X ---------------X-------------X---->
         =========================================================
result:  |-------------------A----------------<NULL>--------F---->

             |---- part A ----|         |- part B --|
```

`Part A` or any `part` will happen within a 100ms window. The time between the `parts` is much bigger. In words: If `observB` emits an item, it should continue with or without a value of `observB` But if `observA` emits, it should wait for `observB`

So, what I have so far is only a solution for `part A`

```
| ----- A B C D E -------->
| ------------------X ---->
===========zip===============
|-------------------A----->


Observable.zip(
    observA$.throttle(100),
    observB$, (a, b => a)
   .subscribe(...)
```

which doesn't work for `part B` because it will wait for `observA`. I'm not sure how to solve this with RxJS, so any help would be. Maybe I shouldn't do this with RxJs only. Any help would be appreciated

UPDATE: [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/40h4b8x7/7/), thanks to @martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use something along these lines:

```
Observable.defer(() => {
    return observA$.withLatestFrom(observB$.take(1).startWith(null), v => v)
  })
  .take(1)
  .repeat()
  .subscribe(...);
```

It takes always the first value from `observB$` and then waits until an emission `observA$`. Then it repeats this process with `take(1).repeat()`.

Comment: Why do you have the `defer`, I noticed that my demo also works without: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/40h4b8x7/8/) ?

Comment: It's required to trigger the callback every time `repeat` resubscribes.

Comment: Sounds logic, but can you explain why my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/40h4b8x7/8/)  works without `defer`?

Comment: You're emitting just one item so the chain completes with `take(1)` and that's all. When I'm thinking about it maybe `defer` isn't necessary but I'm not 100% sure about it.